# Menu bar icons get hidden by long menu bar items

Tags: menu-bar, window-manager

Sometimes on my Macbook Pro when I have a lot of icons in the menu bar, if I start an application which has a lot of menu items, some of these icons get automatically obscured by the menu items.

For example, when running iTunes, the Twitter icon gets obscured...

[image]

...but if I switch to Finder (which has a fewer menu items) the icon then re-appears

[image]

Is there any way I can show or get to these obscured icons without having to switch to an application with a shorter menu bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been using this for a while and it seems to be configurable to do what you need.

http://www.macbartender.com

[image]

Comment: Note that MacBartender is a paid app.  $15 today.

Answer (score 17):

When holding the <kbd>command</kbd> key you can drag the menu bar items around and change their order.

That just helped me when I switched to an app where I could see the required menu bar item and then I moved it far to the right so that I could then see it also in the other app.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Big Sur, at least. :(

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks for the tip! Also @SeanRobertson I just did it on Big Sur, so maybe try again?

Comment: This is a good hack, but it is infuriating that there is no simple way to show icons that are hidden behind the notch on new MBP

Comment: Works on Ventura 13.4 (22F66)

Answer (score 12):

An app called [AccessMenuBarApps](http://www.ortisoft.de/en/accessmenubarapps/) allows you to do that by basically providing a keyboard shortcut to an application with no application menu items. It's free, so it wouldn't hurt to give it a try.

Comment: +1 Good find, thanks! That works pretty well actually, with the minor exception that there doesn't seem to be an option to hide its dock icon! Frankly I'm a little amazed that along with the other slick features and tricks in OS X that theres no option to, say, temporarily slide or swipe the menu bar out the way. Perhaps its just not a problem for most people...

Comment: Use Dockless (http://homepage.mac.com/fahrenba/programs/dockless/dockless.html) to hide the icon for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that also seems to disable the menu bar completely for the application whose icon is to be hidden. Probably just a GUI wrapper round the [LSUIElement](http://www.macworld.com/article/1153731/hidedockicon.html) trick (EDIT: The dockless readme.rtf confirms this)

Comment: So it pretty much disables the app then? That's probably an apple ui limitation then.

Answer (score 5):

[BetterTouchTool](http://bettertouchtool.net/) has an action that hides all menu items.

You can assign arbitrary keyboard shortcuts or mouse / touchpad gestures.

[image]

<sub>BetterTouchTool is commercial software (pay what you want – $3.99 minimum). During the 45 day trial phase you can use all features of BTT.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I already use BTT for a host of other things. 
Lots of love for BTT. Well worth the price.

Answer (score 1):

[NoMenuBar](http://www.jeb.com.fr/en/nomenubar.shtml) is a free app whose only purpose is to have no menus other than it's name so that you can switch to it and see more menu bar icons.

This isn't a direct solution to the question (not have to switch to another app), but it did help me see more icons that even Finder's menus were obscuring.