# How to access my top menu bar icons on Mac?

Tags: menu-bar

Laptop with the "island" (screenshot):

[image]

External monitor (screenshot):
[image]

Laptop photo (in real life)

[image]

I can rearrange:

> Use the Command key if necessary to drag off menu items or re-arrange them.

Very few settings here:

[image]

## Do I need an app for that?

https://www.macbartender.com/

[image]

Personally I prefer to avoid installing yet another app, I genuinely believe that there should be a way to access all the apps on the menu bar.

Pretty much the same question from 10 years ago: [Menu bar icons get hidden by long menu bar items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/menu-bar-icons-get-hidden-by-long-menu-bar-items) *(before the Macs with the camera island in the middle)*

Comment: This looks rather like a duplicate of the old question too me (as you noted yourself). What would make the question here special enough to keep it separate?

Comment: It's about the new Mac with the camera being part of the screen, I think it changes the logistics.

Comment: The solution is still the same: install any of the helper apps from the store, there is just not enough room for a longer menu *and* the camera *and* the icons.